# Replace value with the name of its respective column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
Code    401k    CVS
101A            true
231N    true
FD54    true
99JB    
85F4    true
```

I'm trying to replace the "true" character values with the respective column name (e.g. "401k"). This is my desired output:

```
Code    401k    CVS
101A            CVS
231N    401k
FD54    401k
99JB    
85F4    401k
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The coding below enabled me to replace every "true" value (character) into its respective column name.

```
##Replace every "true" value with its respective column name
w <- which(df=="true",arr.ind=TRUE)
df[w] <- names(df)[w[,"col"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This first method will do it without coercing the data to character first:

```
wc <- droplevels(col(df, as.factor=TRUE)[which(df == "true")])
df[levels(wc)] <- Map(factor, df[levels(wc)], labels = levels(wc))
df
#   Code  401k  CVS
# 1 101A  <NA>  CVS
# 2 231N  401k <NA>
# 3 FD54  401k <NA>
# 4 99JB  <NA> <NA>
# 5 85F4  401k <NA>
```

Or you can use `which` with the data frame indices and convert everything to character:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) levels(x)[x])
w <- which(df == "true", arr.ind = TRUE)
df[w] <- names(df)[w[,"col"]]
df
#   Code  401K  CVS
# 1 101A  <NA>  CVS
# 2 231N  401K <NA>
# 3 FD54  401K <NA>
# 4 99JB  <NA> <NA>
# 5 85F4  401K <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you, Richard, for your help. I used the which() function and was able to successfully obtain the desired output.