# Conditionally replace values of subset of rows with column name in R using only tidy

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a way to conditionally replace certain values in a subset of columns with that column name staying in the tidyverse.  See example below:

```
wl <- data_frame(x=1:4,
  multi=c("Y","Y","Y","Y"),
  ABC=c("","Y","Y",""), 
  ABD=c("","","",""),
  ABE=c("Y","Y","","Y"))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
      x multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Y     ""    ""    Y    
2     2 Y     Y     ""    Y    
3     3 Y     Y     ""    ""   
4     4 Y     ""    ""    Y   

df <- wl %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("AB")),
         funs(replace(.,.=='Y',values="column name")))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      x multi ABC         ABD   ABE        
  <int> <chr> <chr>       <chr> <chr>      
1     1 Y     ""          ""    column name
2     2 Y     column name ""    column name
3     3 Y     column name ""    ""         
4     4 Y     ""          ""    column name
```

except it would be the actual column name instead of 'column name'.  I've used two different answers on here to get to both mutating on conditional columns (which is how I got to my example) and how to replace certains values with a column name (not used in my current example but the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703363/r-replace-value-with-the-name-of-its-respective-column)).

I can combine the two answers to get it to work:

```
w <- which(df=="column name",arr.ind=TRUE)
df[w] <- names(df)[w[,"col"]]                 
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      x multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Y     ""    ""    ABE  
2     2 Y     ABC   ""    ABE  
3     3 Y     ABC   ""    ""   
4     4 Y     ""    ""    ABE
```

I acknowledge the process above is completely functional but out of pure curiosity, is there a way to do this without the second chunk of code?  Is there some function I can plug into the `values=` portion of the `replace(.,.=='Y',values="column name")` step that can capture the column name and perform this entire process within a single `mutate_at` function?

Comment: You can stay within the tidyverse and `gather`, then `mutate` then `spread`, such as `wl %>% 
  gather(ColName,Result, matches("AB")) %>% 
  mutate(Result = if_else(Result =="Y", ColName, Result)) %>% 
  spread(ColName, Result)`

Comment: @KerryJackson ahh, very clever and so simple...I like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a little tidyeval in your `mutate_at` function to get the column name, then an `ifelse` (or whatever other logic structure you might want) to replace certain values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

wl %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("AB")), function(x) {
    x_var <- rlang::enquo(x)
    ifelse(x == "Y", rlang::quo_name(x_var), x)
  })
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>       x multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 Y     ""    ""    ABE  
#> 2     2 Y     ABC   ""    ABE  
#> 3     3 Y     ABC   ""    ""   
#> 4     4 Y     ""    ""    ABE
```

Created on 2018-08-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Great, works like a charm and keeps it inside mutate_at

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `imap`

```
library(purrr)
AB_cols <- grep("^AB", names(wl)) # find positions of columns that start with "AB"
wl[AB_cols] <- imap(.x = wl[AB_cols], .f = ~replace(.x, .x == "Y", .y))
wl
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#      x multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 Y     ""    ""    ABE  
#2     2 Y     ABC   ""    ABE  
#3     3 Y     ABC   ""    ""   
#4     4 Y     ""    ""    ABE
```

Comment: Strange that in your answer it shows that your code replaces the multi column (which I don't want) but when I run it in my R it produces my target (only replaces the AB columns).

Comment: I need it to work with or similarly to starts_with("AB") because my real data frame is much larger than my example and I don't want to have to always manually count the column index numbers.  Still a useful function to learn though! Thanks

Comment: @c.custer Edited my answer regarding your second comment. But what do you mean by "your code replaces the multi column"?

Comment: look at your output tibble.  All of the "Y" have been replaced by "multi" which is it's column.  It's strange because when I ran your code it did not do that.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidy verse`

```
library(dplyr)
wl %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("AB")),
     funs(c("", deparse(substitute(.)))[(.=="Y" & !is.na(.)) + 1]))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#     x multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 Y     ""    ""    ABE  
#2     2 Y     ABC   ""    ABE  
#3     3 Y     ABC   ""    ""   
#4     4 Y     ""    ""    ABE
```

---

Using `base R`

```
nm1 <- grep("^AB", names(wl))
i1 <- wl[,(nm1)] == "Y" & !is.na(wl[,(nm1)])
wl[,(nm1)][i1] <- names(wl)[(nm1)][col(wl[,(nm1)])][i1]
wl
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#      x multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 Y     ""    ""    ABE  
#2     2 Y     ABC   ""    ABE  
#3     3 Y     ABC   ""    ""   
#4     4 Y     ""    ""    ABE
```

---

Or we can do this faster by assigning in place with `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(wl)
for(j in nm1) set(wl, i=which(wl[[j]] == "Y"), j=j, names(wl)[j])
wl
#   x multi ABC ABD ABE
#1: 1     Y         ABE
#2: 2     Y ABC     ABE
#3: 3     Y ABC        
#4: 4     Y         ABE
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  But I need it to work with or similarly to starts_with("AB") because my real data frame is much larger than my example and I don't want to have to always manually count the column index numbers.

Comment: @c.custer. Okay, changed it to more dynamic

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And thanks for providing multiple approaches.  Always good to have more tools

Comment: Your tidyverse example works but I honestly don't understand what it's doing?  Where/how is it capturing the column name?

Comment: @c.custer It is the `deparse(substitute` step captures the name before evaluating

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace_na`:

```
wl%>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('AB')),~`is.na<-`(.x,.x=='Y'))%>%
   replace_na(set_names(as.list(names(.)),names(.)))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  x     multi ABC   ABD   ABE  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     Y     ""    ""    ABE  
2 2     Y     ABC   ""    ABE  
3 3     Y     ABC   ""    ""   
4 4     Y     ""    ""    ABE
```

Comment: Another great answer!  I think my one concern is my real data may be reading in NAs and not actual blank characters (my fault for not showing this in the example).  Though I imagine just using your code twice to replace the actual NAs and then the Y's would work just as well.  Thanks!