# Conditional merging on multiple columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table, reshape, melt

I have two data.tables. I want to merge information from the second data.table with the first:

```
DT1 <- fread(
"Val C   D  E   F   iso   year   
1    NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2001
1    NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2002       
1    NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001             
1    NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2002",
header = TRUE)

DT2 <- fread(
"Val name  O   P  Q   R   iso   year   
1   A     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2001
1   A     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2001   
1   B     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2001
1   B     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2002
1   A     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2002
1   B     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2002         
1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001  
1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001
1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001        
1   A     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2002
1   A     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2002          
1   B     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2002",
header = TRUE)
```

I want to add the information under `name` of `DT2` to `DT1` as follows. If for `iso` == `NLD` the name `A` exists (no matter how often), the column A is filled with A, if not it remains NA:

```
DT1 <- fread(
"Val    C   D  E   F   iso   year   A B C
 1      NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2001   A B NA
 1      NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2002   A B NA   
 1      NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001   NA NA C         
 1      NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2002   A B NA",
header = TRUE)
```

But I don't know how to get there. I have been trying something like:

```
DT[,A:="A"]
DT[,B:="B"]
DT[,C:="C"]
DT2$name[DT, on=c(iso="iso", year="year", name="A"), nomatch=0L]
```

or

```
merge(DT, DT2$name, on=c(iso="iso", year="year", A="name"), all.x = TRUE, allow.cartesian=FALSE)
```

But I think have to solve it differently. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: So "O P  Q  R" columns are not relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the output you want, but perhaps: `DT3 <- merge(DT1, DT2, by=c('Val', 'iso', 'year'), all=T)`, followed by `DT3[iso=='NLD' & name == 'A', A := 'A']`

Comment: @zx8754 Indeed. I mostly complicate the example a little bit, because otherwise I sometimes get solutions that are not general enough to apply to the actual data. Only the `name` column is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape *DT2* before merging, something like below. We will need one more step to change count numbers to A, B, C:

```
merge(DT1, dcast(DT2[, -c(3:6)], iso + year + Val ~ name),
      by = c("iso", "year", "Val"))
# Using 'year' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
# Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#    iso year Val C.x D  E  F A B C.y
# 1: GRC 2001   1  NA 3 NA NA 0 0   3
# 2: GRC 2002   1  NA 3 NA NA 2 1   0
# 3: NLD 2001   1  NA 1 NA NA 2 1   0
# 4: NLD 2002   1  NA 2 NA NA 1 2   0
```

Comment: You can make the extra columns the actual letters by using a custom `fun.aggregate` in `dcast` e.g. with `dt2_wd <- 
dcast(dt2, iso + year + Val ~ name, value.var = 'name', 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) x[1])` then
`merge(dt1, dt2_wd, by = c("iso", "year", "Val"))` gives the output shown in the question (except row order and the last column name)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using a key to merge:

```
library(data.table)
#adding a key column "temp" to both DT1 and DT2
DT1[,temp:=paste0(iso,year,"_",D)]
DT2[,temp:=paste0(iso,year,"_",P)]
#merge accoring to "temp"
DT3 <- merge(DT1,DT2)
#Casting variable name, a warning pops-out saying it uses lenght as aggregation
DT3 <- dcast(merge(DT1,DT2),Val+C+D+E+F+iso+year~name)

#output
DT3
   Val  C D  E  F iso year A B C
1:   1 NA 1 NA NA NLD 2001 1 1 0
2:   1 NA 2 NA NA NLD 2002 0 2 0
3:   1 NA 3 NA NA GRC 2001 0 0 3
4:   1 NA 3 NA NA GRC 2002 2 1 0
```

Finally to convert into the desired form using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703363/replace-value-with-the-name-of-its-respective-column) answer, I'm transforming it back to data frame to change the values of last three columns A, B, C. Note that C is repeated so I'm calling them as index.

```
DT_final <- as.data.frame(DT3)
ind <- which(DT_final[,8:10]>0,arr.ind=TRUE) # is there a positive value?
DT_final[,8:10][ind]<- names(DT_final[,8:10])[ind[,"col"]]# if so change to the column name.
ind <- which(DT_final[,8:10]==0 ,arr.ind=TRUE)# is there zero  value?
DT_final[,8:10][ind]<- NA # if so change to NA

DT_final
  Val  C D  E  F iso year    A    B    C
1   1 NA 1 NA NA NLD 2001    A    B <NA>
2   1 NA 2 NA NA NLD 2002 <NA>    B <NA>
3   1 NA 3 NA NA GRC 2001 <NA> <NA>    C
4   1 NA 3 NA NA GRC 2002    A    B <NA>
```