# Replace a value when is >0 in a column with a character of another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In a data frame, I would like to replace the values greater than 1  in a column with the character present in another column.

[Description dataframe and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMBDp.png)

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: I think this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703363/replace-value-with-the-name-of-its-respective-column

Answer (score 1):

I found  the solution:

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <-df %>% mutate(Sample_1 = ifelse(as.numeric(Sample_1==0), m.Sample_1,as.character(knr)))%>%
  mutate(Sample_2 = ifelse(as.numeric(Sample_2==0), Sample_2,as.character(knr)))%>%
  mutate(Sample_3 = ifelse(as.numeric(Sample_3==0), Sample_3,as.character(knr)))
  mutate(m.Surface = ifelse(as.numeric(m.Surface==0), m.Surface,as.character(knr))
```